# Skipping www in file hosts

Tags: c, linux

So, i have small programm.
I had a question regarding a small piece in my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *host_file = fopen("/etc/hosts","r");
    if(host_file == NULL){
        printf("Can't open host file.");
    }

    char str[10000];
    char pattern[256];
    unsigned int i;
    while(fgets(str, 10000, host_file) != NULL) {
        i = 0;
        char *c = str;
        while(*c != EOF && *c != '\n') {
            if( *c != ' ' && *c != '\t'){
                pattern[i++] = *c;
            }else{
                pattern[i] = '\0';
                printf("%s ", pattern);
                i = 0;       
            }
        *c++;
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

host_file this is file `/etc/hosts` of Linux.
Doesn't matter what doing my programm.
It matters how this piece of code works.

```
if( *c != ' ' && *c != '\t'){
    pattern[i++] = *c;
}else{
    pattern[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", pattern);
    i = 0;       
}
```

Logically, the pattern should output every word in a string, but the program produces a strange result:
[image]

File hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   NameOfMyPc
127.0.0.1   phpmyadmin.loc www.phpmyadmin.loc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

1.1.1.. test.loc www.test.loc
```

Please explain why this happens?
Very interesting...

Comment: The comparison to EOF seems wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
if( *c != ' ' && *c != '\t'){
    pattern[i++] = *c;
}
```

causes the program to accumulate characters other than spaces or tabs. Then this code:

```
else{
    pattern[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s ", pattern);
    i = 0;       
}
```

causes the program to print the accumulated text, but only when a space or tab is seen. Nothing causes the program to print the accumulated text when the end of a line is seen. Thus, the last “word” (text without a space or tab) of a line is never printed. The program prints its input with the last word removed from each line.

The logic of the code needs to be redesigned. An easy “fix” is to print the accumulated text when the end of a line is seen. However, this results in a program that merely copies its input to its output, and then the processing to recognize spaces or tabs seems pointless, so why is it there at all? If you are going to continue developing the program to remove “www.” from names in the hosts file, you need to state that clearly in the question so advice about a good fix can be given.

Additionally:

`*c != EOF` is wrong. `EOF` is an `int` value and should be compared to the `int` returned by various routines, such as `getchar`. Comparing it to a `char`, which `*c` is, is wrong.

`*c++;` should be just `c++;`, as its only effect is to increment `c`. Dereferencing to obtain the `char` value is pointless as nothing is done with it.

Comment: Eric, 1.Thank you very much for your help, I don’t understand how I myself overlooked this.
2. To process words with 'www', just add the output of the 'pattern' after iterating over the letters.

Comment: This is why `isspace()` exists.

Comment: @technosaurus: `isspace` is affected by locale and would accept characters that might not be appropriate in `hosts`, such as `\v`. And recognizing space characters was not a cause of the error in the code in the question.